# custom property with google marker in type script

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, typescript1.7

I'm using type script and getting below error when trying to set custom property with Google marker. 
Can anyone please advice how to set custom property with Google Map Marker?

> Argument of type '{ position: LatLng; map: any; icon: string; zIndex: number; se10: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'MarkerOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'se10' does not exist in type 'MarkerOptions'.

The following Javascript code is working well.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(merchant[lat]), Number(merchant[lng])),
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            zIndex: zIndex ,
            se10: merchant.se
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Got it  . below is type script code -

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(merchant[lat]), Number(merchant[lng])),
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                zIndex: zIndex ,
            });
            marker.set("se10",merchant.se);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you get a new error that `Property 'se10' does not exist on type Marker`? Or did you not define "marker" as type `google.maps.Marker`?

Comment: My IDE offered me to use string literal to avoid error - `marker[\`se10\`]`

Comment: I lost quite a lot of time with this problem today. Thanks to your @Raj.