# Getting marker info from markerclusterer

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have pushed markers into the a markerClusterer. When I click on the markerClusterer I want to display the info of the nmarkers in the cluster. However, when I use the getMarkers() method, it does not give me the info that I stored in marker, only data about the marker itself. Is there any way that I can implement this? https://codesandbox.io/s/joey-gmaps-c5kdf

```
    const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [],
      { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function (c) {
      console.log('Number of managed markers in cluster: ' + c.getSize());
      var m = c.getMarkers();
      for (i in m) {
        console.log(Object.values(m[i]));
        console.log(m[i].getTitle());
        console.log(m[i].toString());
      }
      var p = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        p.push(m[i]);
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your markers' information using `getMarkers` so there may be an issue somewhere in your code implementation that you haven't posted.

Try the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6wm7xtf/) based off of Google's [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering).

JS code below:

```
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    }
  });

  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length],
      title: location.lat.toString() + "," + location.lng.toString(),
      myObj: { myKey: i }
    });
  });

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(c) {
    console.log('Number of managed markers in cluster: ' + c.getSize());
    var m = c.getMarkers();
    for (let i in m) {
      console.log(m[i].getLabel());
      console.log(m[i].getTitle());
      console.log(m[i].myObj.myKey);
    }
  });
}

var locations = [{
    lat: -31.563910,
    lng: 147.154312
  },
  {
    lat: -33.718234,
    lng: 150.363181
  },
  {
    lat: -33.727111,
    lng: 150.371124
  },
  {
    lat: -33.848588,
    lng: 151.209834
  },
  {
    lat: -33.851702,
    lng: 151.216968
  },
  {
    lat: -34.671264,
    lng: 150.863657
  },
  {
    lat: -35.304724,
    lng: 148.662905
  },
  {
    lat: -36.817685,
    lng: 175.699196
  },
  {
    lat: -36.828611,
    lng: 175.790222
  },
  {
    lat: -37.750000,
    lng: 145.116667
  },
  {
    lat: -37.759859,
    lng: 145.128708
  },
  {
    lat: -37.765015,
    lng: 145.133858
  },
  {
    lat: -37.770104,
    lng: 145.143299
  },
  {
    lat: -37.773700,
    lng: 145.145187
  },
  {
    lat: -37.774785,
    lng: 145.137978
  },
  {
    lat: -37.819616,
    lng: 144.968119
  },
  {
    lat: -38.330766,
    lng: 144.695692
  },
  {
    lat: -39.927193,
    lng: 175.053218
  },
  {
    lat: -41.330162,
    lng: 174.865694
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.439506
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.501315
  },
  {
    lat: -42.735258,
    lng: 147.438000
  },
  {
    lat: -43.999792,
    lng: 170.463352
  }
]
```

If e.g. you click on the blue cluster #3, you'll get the following output logged in the console:

```
Number of managed markers in cluster: 3
T
-42.734358,147.439506
U
-42.734358,147.501315
V
-42.735258,147.438
```

**Edit:** This error appears to be typescript related. There's a solution in related thread [custom property with google marker in type script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542083/custom-property-with-google-marker-in-type-script)

Please try the code below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  const marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: features[i].position,
    icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: map
  });
  marker2.set("customInfo", features[i].location);
  console.log("Marker222223", marker2["customInfo"]);
  markerCluster.addMarker(marker2);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lets say I wanted to get to attach my own object to this marker instead of a label or title, is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I get the error **"Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'myObj' does not exist in type 'ReadonlyMarkerOptions."**, same problem as @SUNIL JADHAV comment below

Comment: I dont get this error, can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this from our side? Ideally in a codesandbox or stackblitz.

Comment: the code is too complicated to reproduce since I am using servers... is it possible we can screenshare

Comment: It wouldn't be appropriate nor useful for the community to screen-share in this site. Please can you try creating a minimal example that can reproduce this error so that I can check what's wrong?

Comment: thank you... I have added a codesandbox example to my post

Comment: Thanks I see the problem and it looks like it's typescript related. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

While creating markers add object into marker so that each marker will have asociated object with it i.e. customInfo

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: accident_LatLng,
        title: accident_title,
        map: map,
        customInfo: object,


      });
```

to Access marker object use below code. I have created custom array to store marker object.

```
 var markers = cluster.getMarkers();
          var markerCustom = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markerCustom.push(cluster.markers_[i].customInfo)
          }
```

Hope this helps

Reference https://medium.com/@sunil.jadhav38/implementing-marker-clustering-is-angular-using-google-charts-6b62a33f3b61

Comment: It says that I can not assign customInfo to the marker object : "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'customInfo' does not exist in type 'ReadonlyMarkerOptions'."